# my azure sql database is not connecting with SSMS 2014

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database

The firewall contain my IP in valid list but I am still getting error in connection. I tried the command

```
C:\Users\MianAsbat>SQLCMD -U username -P password -S
```

and got the following response. I am trying from windows 8 virtual machine on mac. Please help. Thanks.

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server: 
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [67].
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server: 
>   Login timeout expired.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server: 
>   A network-related or in stance-specific error has occurred while establishing 
>   a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. 
>   Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow 
>   remote connections. For more information see  SQL Server Books Online..

Comment: Is port 1433 opened on your company's firewall list ? Even if your IP is listed on the Azure portal in the allowed list, port 1433 is required to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert the database name:

```
sqlcmd -U ProvideLogin@Server -P ProvidePassword -S ProvideServerName -d ProvideDatabaseName
```

[Client quick-start code samples to SQL Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336280.aspx)